# Will my app stay in the app store after I stopped paying developer fee to Apple?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030889/what-happens-to-my-apps-after-my-developer-account-membership-expires)

where the marked answer, from June 2010 is "Your apps will be removed" however, another person answers that apps will *not* be removed, and claims as recent as February this year to be sure of this.

I think [Apple support pages](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html) are very vague on this matter.

**Is there anyone out there who knows for sure what happens?**

(I hope this behavior is okay (re-asking the same question in a new post) - ideally a bump of that thread would have been my choose, but I don't know how to do that, or if it is possible on Stack Overflow. I don't have enough reputation to comment or edit the other question.)

Comment: I just sent the exact same question to Apple using http://developer.apple.com/contact/

Comment: The last answer by Vijay Shankar says just that; it was posted in August, edited in October, then there's two follow-up comments from the end of February.

Comment: Yes, but Vijay Shankar's comment appears to be based on a misreading of a piece of text from Apple's website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

See http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html:

> If I don't renew my membership will my
>   application(s) still function for
>   those customers who have already
>   installed my application(s) from the
>   App Store?
>
> Yes. Although you will lose App Store
>   distribution, your application(s) will
>   still function for customers who have
>   installed your application(s) from the
>   App Store on their device(s).

It makes commercial good sense for Apple to stop featuring your app in their store when you're not paying the yearly fee, since the infrastructure used to host your app would still be an ongoing cost for them.

Also, if Apple didn't purge non-paying customer's apps, over time the app store would become a huge aggregation of unmaintained apps which would dwarf newer higher quality apps. Remember that Apple often releases updates to iOS which requires updates and tweaks to existing apps -- for them to keep stale unmaintained apps around just doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Voted down because your extra explanation is not reasonable!

Comment: In which way is it not reasonable?

Comment: Because I think Apple is aggressively overcharging everyone including developers, because of its monopoly. For example Google Play has only one-time $25 fee. Moreover I don't think hosting few megabytes would cost $100 per year and there is no problem with older apps as you have mentioned on Google Play. Recently App Store removed one of my free and ad-free games with more than 50k downloads just after few month because my first year subscription was over.

Comment: Our membership expired and our app can't be found in the app store atm, after renewing the membership, does anyone know how long before our app becomes available again?

Answer (score 7):

Today I got this reply from Apple Developer Support:

> As for your inquiry regarding to program renewal, please know that we advise you that your application will be removed from the App Store upon your expiration date unless you renew. If you'd like to continue to distribute your application on the App Store beyond your current expiration date, you'll need to renew into the Program before your current Program expires.

Comment: Guys, if i revnew my account after removed my app from store i will must upload new build?

Answer (score 5):

i can confirm that your app will be removed from the apple app store if you do not renew you apple developer program account. it just happened me, what a bummer. Hope this helps clarify this question