# Not prolonging my iOS Dev Account, what will happen to my App?

Tags: ios, account

I wrote one bad selling app. Since the revenue does not even cover the iOS Dev account, I thought about not prolonging it. What would then happen to my app and the sales I have in future?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to my apps after my developer account membership expires?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030889/what-happens-to-my-apps-after-my-developer-account-membership-expires)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not renew your iOS developer account then your app will be removed from sale once the account expires.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will not be available for purchase any longer, but beware that it will still appear in the App Store with the information and screenshots that you have provided.

Comment: If I make it a free app? Will it then be still available for download?

Comment: No. In order to offer any apps (free or paid) you must pay the annual fee!