# Can previous customers still download iOS apps for which the developer account has expired?

Tags: ios, app-store

Apple [states](https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/) that once a developer account for the iOS App Store expires, its published apps can no longer be downloaded.

Does this only affect new customers, or will users who have downloaded the app while it was still available be able to redownload it from their "past purchases" section in the App Store or iTunes?

I know that this has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030889/what-happens-to-my-apps-after-my-developer-account-membership-expires) in the past, but those answers either predate or do not mention the "past purchases" feature of the App Store.

(For example, I am still able to download a certain bird-themed jumping game from that section, even though it is no longer listed in the store; however, in that case, the app has probably only been depublished even though the associated developer account is still available.)

Comment: No. I wrote an app for a guy and downloaded it from the App Store. His account expired and I can no longer see it. He didn't manually remove it.

Comment: We have withdrawn an app from the store, but we cannot delete the app from itunes connect. From that I gather that past users will still be able to download it even though it is no longer available to new users. (our account is of course still active)

Answer (score 2):

Apple documents about [expired membership](https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/) -

> Expired Memberships If your Apple Developer Program membership
>   expires, your apps will no longer be available for download and you
>   will not be able to submit new apps or updates. You will lose access
>   to pre-release software, Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, and
>   Technical Support Incidents. However, your apps will still function
>   for users who have already installed or downloaded them, and you will
>   still have access to iTunes Connect and free development resources.
>
> If your Apple Developer Enterprise Program membership expires, your
>   apps will no longer be available for download and will no longer
>   function for those who have already installed or downloaded them. You
>   will still have access to free development resources.

This means If your developer account expired then yours app not available for download for both new and old user.But still app will be functional if user already install or downloaded into their device. In this case In App purchase will be work. But He/She if delete the app then he/she can't download further this app until developer account renew.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your question I decided to test this for myself. I was able to locate Tap Tap Revenge 3 in my purchase history, download it, and install it on my iPhone 5c running iOS 8.3. The game doesn't function anymore as the game servers have shut down, but it was able to run beyond the launch image at least, which suggests that the app can indeed run provided it doesn't have compatibility issues or depend on any servers that have been taken offline.

[Tapulous shut down in January 2014](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Tapulous-Tap-Tap-series-officially-becomes-iOS-gaming-history_id51244) and I don't expect their developer account to still be active today. According to the linked article, IAPs cannot be restored, so there is that. I can confirm that the app itself is still available for download in my purchase history, however.

Comment: Didn't think testing past purchases would be one of the last things I'd ever do on an iPhone before finally making the switch to a Windows Phone... seems pretty fitting now that I think about it.