# What would happen if I change itunes Connect developer membership from Individual to a Company?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes-app

As if now I am running an individual account for itunes connect membership, what if I want to change it to a company account ?

Do my existing apps stay?, what about the account information ?, Account should be in the name of company now ?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/support/account/ – under the heading "*Can I switch my membership from an individual to an organization?*"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly related to programming.

Comment: love-hate relationship with C and strong opinions about Java...lol
Thanks Hamish

Comment: Yes please, go ahead.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030889/what-happens-to-my-apps-after-my-developer-account-membership-expires]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to create the company developer membership, then transfer the apps from your individual account to the company membership. Details [Transferring and Deleting Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)