# Do locally installed iOS apps have an expiration date?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have built a hybrid app and installed it on an iPad via Xcode. The question now is. Will it work forever? or is there a built-in counter or expiration date that will cause the to be unusable if I don't renew it or  my Apple Developer license expires?

Comment: your app will continue to operate. you can not update etc... refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030889/what-happens-to-my-apps-after-my-developer-account-membership-expires

Comment: you can use the app after your license is expired

Comment: @AmodGokhale this is true for AppStore account, but not for AdHoc or apps running using the developers provisioning profile.

Comment: @rckoenes i just tried an app who was installed through xcode on simulator and using developer profile ( which is now expired ) account is not renewed. Now this app ran without any issue. Are you saying I cannot do this in real phone?

Comment: Aha, but is there any way to have it installed in-house and make it be installed forever without renew license?

Comment: @PeterWesterlund - it just worked for me on simulator for an expired profile. https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal/ doesn't say anything that you cannot use it in real phone with exported .ipa? So it should work but do share if you find instances of otherwise

Comment: It's confusing when you @AmodGokhale and rckoenes says two different things. So, rckoenes says it should expire. But AmodGokhale believe it remains working? No clear answers here. So if I understand this right, it SHOULD be stopped but it COULD be running anyway?

Comment: @PeterWesterlund what rckoenes mentioned above is correct statement. App I checked above on simulator was with AppStore Account, your app will not work after expiration if it's created using AdHoc account. Any live app will continue to work without any issue after expiration if created with AppStore Account.

Comment: @Amod Gokhale But if I distribute with Enterprise for in-house then? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html. I don't know how that works, haven't got that far. Seems it exports to devices from Xcode. Don't understand how, do they need to be connected with USB cable to the computer? Anyway. How about the expiry date for this method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136530/discussion-between-amod-gokhale-and-peter-westerlund).

Comment: Okay seems people don't like this question. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app is singed with a **provisioning profile**, this profile has an **expiry date**.

So **yes it will expire**, and you will have to update the provisioning profile on your device. For this you will need an active developer account.

You can find expiration date in Xcode through menu `Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts`, select your Apple ID and double click the your team or personal team.

[image: Provisioning Profiles in Xcode]

Edit: Xcode 9.2 doesn't show Provisioning profiles anymore in Accounts settings.

Comment: Although the iPad is not connected to the Internet? And where can I see the exact date?

Comment: You can see the expire date in Xcode, when you go to the account and view the detail of your account.