# Apple Developer Membership Expires

Tags: ios, app-store, membership, apple-developer

My Apple Developer Membership is expiring and at the moment I don't want renew it, I would like to know what happens to the app (besides obviously to disappear from the App Store) the app in the account will be removed to? Can someone else create an app with the same name as mine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to my apps after my developer account membership expires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030889/what-happens-to-my-apps-after-my-developer-account-membership-expires)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. I would like to know what happens to the app (besides obviously to disappear from the App Store) the app in the account will be removed to?

You apps won't be removed from developer account but will be removed from App store (it won't be visible/accessible to end-user).

> 2. Can someone else create an app with the same name as mine?

No

Answer (score 3):

If your **Apple Developer Program membership expires**, your apps will no longer be available for download and you will not be able to submit new apps or updates. You will lose access to pre-release software, Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, and Technical Support Incidents. However, your apps will still function for users who have already installed or downloaded them, and you will still have access to iTunes Connect and free development resources.

if your **Apple Developer Enterprise Program membership expires**, your apps will no longer be available for download and will no longer function for those who have already installed or downloaded them. You will still have access to free development resources.

> "Can someone else create an app with the same name as mine?"
>
> **NO**